# What's a good value option for storing 200GB of data in the cloud?

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-ec2, storage

I've got about 200GB of data that I'd like to serve on a low-volume web site. I've currently got this on shared hosting at Dreamhost, but I'd like to upgrade to something that gives me root access like Amazon EC2. Although running an Amazon EC2 instance 24/7 looks more expensive than the competition, $0.10/GB-month for EBS appears to be a very good rate for storage. Is there anybody offering comparable storage for less?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just wanting to serve the data out, you can do so via amazon's S3.  You do *not* get root (or a shell of any type), but there are plenty of tools to deal with S3.

Answer (score 1):

If the website is low volume and you are simply worried about storage, move the 200G to Amazon's S3 and then service http requests via a web server on some inexpensive VPS. I have used S3 myself and have had great luck. It's extremely simple to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are after but www.servage.net offer stupid ammounts of space for about £50 per year. it may be worth a look.
The offer almost unlimited bandwidth I seem to remember also!